# Is it dangerous to obfuscate email addresses with document.write?

Tags: javascript, security

I generate an email address on a website in javascript to make it a little bit more difficult for scrapers. Basically I have a few variables and then jumble them back together with javascript.

```
var a = new Array('test','example','.com','@');
document.write(a[0]+a[3]+a[1]+a[2]);
```

Two questions:

1. Is this effective?
2. Someone told me it is dangerous, because "document.write" is insecure? How could this be exploited?

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/802894/1577396) may help you.

Comment: 1. Don't know. If the scraping is done not via just grabbing the raw HTML, but running it though a headless browser, you obfuscation attempt will be useless. 2. Regarding `document.write`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this effective?

Moderately, but it is [trivial to bypass](http://blog.dorward.me.uk/2006/02/02/spambots_that_drink_coffee.html) if a spambot writer wants to go to the effort.

> Someone told me it is dangerous, because "document.write" is insecure? How could this be exploited?

It can't. `document.write` is insecure only if you take improperly sanitised external data (such as part of the URL) and use it in the argument.